# People can ‘abide by’ the law, but can the law ‘abide people’?

Tags: verbs, word-usage, transitivity

Time magazine copy chief and copy editor pointed out the grammatical errors of many movie titles, and suggested corrections in the article of Time magazine (May 24) titled “Writing Wrongs: 10 Movie Titles with Bad Grammar.” 
There was the following suggestion on the title of “Law Abiding Citizen”:

> “Some citizens the law can abide; others it cannot stand.” Suggested
>   fix: A hyphen Law-Abiding Citizen

Oxford English Dictionary defines ‘abide’ as a verb:

> 1 [no object] (abide by) accept or act in accordance with (a rule, decision, or recommendation):
>   2 [with object] (can/could not abide) be unable to tolerate.
>   3 [no object] (of a feeling or memory) continue without fading or being lost.

I understand citizens can **abide by law** and we are mostly **law-abiding** citizens. But can the law **abide** citizens as used in “Some citizens the law can abide"?

Comment: I like the final sentence of your question. I think it'd be well suited for philosophy.se... =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "core" sense of *abide* is much bound up with *wait (for a thing), withstand, sustain/maintain"*.

But one specific and relatively common sense today is to *suffer, tolerate*. [Here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cannot%20abide%20a%20vacuum%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are dozens of written instances of *[Nature] cannot abide a vacuum* where that meaning is applied metaphorically.

I therefore don't see any problem with, for example,...

> There are some citizens the law can abide. Others (such as armed terrorists) can never be tolerated.

The sense of the word in *law-abiding citizen* is somewhat different. Here it means *To stand firm by, remain true to; to **act in accordance with**, submit to* (OED definition 14).

OP's citation from Time magazine humorously/flippantly juxtaposes the two different senses, in a context where all the editor is really interested in saying is that *law-abiding citizen* needs a hyphen.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a *by* after "abide" in "some citizens the law can abide"?

Comment: @Pacerier: I can see where you're coming from, but actually the answer is *No*. If you *abide **by** something*, that "something" has to be, for example, a *rule* - that's to say *to abide by = to respect, conform to* (presumably in the sense of *abide = **remain** [within certain preset boundaries]*). But if you *cannot abide [something]* with no preposition, it just means you can't *stand, tolerate, put up with* whatever thing you find totally unacceptable.

Answer (score 3):

*Law* is the object of *abiding* there, not the subject.  It’s just like with a ***gun-carrying populace***: the people carry guns, not vice versa.  You can see the same thing with other equivalent constructions, like an *apple-eating contest* or a *bridge-building exercise*.  It all these cases, the first word is the logical object of the participial verb.

Answer (score -1):

Is it so much more difficult to abide using a dictionary than it is to abide on line for an answer? It's hard to abide laziness.

Comment: The [McDude meta-abides](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38213/51214).