# abide + direct object?

Tags: grammaticality

[Sample Casebook #2 (2nd Edition) : Garratt v. Dailey, 279 P.2d 1091 | H2O](https://opencasebook.org/casebooks/1640-sample-casebook-2-2nd-edition/resources/1.2.1-garratt-v-dailey-279-p2d-1091/)

> The cause is remanded for clarification, with instructions to make definite findings on the issue of whether Brian Dailey knew with substantial certainty that the plaintiff would attempt to sit down where the chair which he moved had been, and to change the judgment if the findings warrant it.
>
> Costs on this appeal will **abide** the ultimate decision of the superior court. If a judgment is entered for the plaintiff, Ruth Garratt, appellant here, she shall be entitled to her costs on this appeal. If, however, the judgment of dismissal remains unchanged, the respondent will be entitled to recover his costs on this appeal.

I know ["abide" can stand alone as verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/38213), but this is a different case because "abide"  here has direct object. Why not ["abide by"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/114980) here?

Answer (score 2):

The Merriam Webster online dictionary gives [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abide) of "abide" which includes the meaning (number 2)

> to wait for : AWAIT

With the example

> I will abide the coming of my lord. — Alfred Tennyson

This is the sense in which the legal text uses "abide" (although it is probably also a technical legal term with an extra, tighter, definition)

Basically it means that the question of costs is dependent upon the outcome of the superior court case.