# Differences between ABIDE and OBEY

Tags: differences

So I learned from a dictionary that

> **ABIDE** is when you bear something but still do it. Like you don't want to do what your employer tells you but still do.
>
> **OBEY** is to follow a command.

But it looks like they are interchangeable for me. Can someone explain differences, pls.

Comment: Note that "abide" may simply mean "stay" or "reside with".

Comment: And, in general, just because words are (in some sense) synonyms does not mean they are interchangeable.

Comment: I can’t abide people smoking near me.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38213/the-dude-abides-what-does-abide-mean-in-that-context

Comment: "Abide" is a bit old-fashioned.  Most familiar to me in the words of a hymn:  "When darkness deepens, Lord with me abide."

Comment: "Abide" doesn't necessarily mean against one's will. Take law-abiding citizen. The citizen may obey the laws happily.

Comment: I have looked at the seventeen senses and some sub-senses of "abide" in the Oxford English Dictionary and I cannot find one which comes close to "obey". Senses 15 and 16 concern "to suffer", "to bear" or "to endure". That is about as close as I have found, but it doesn't really mean the same thing as  "obey", does it?

Comment: I think the OP is thinking of "abiding by the rules"?

Comment: This makes for a great question if only backed by enough research.

Comment: @WS2 Not only that but _obey_ does not, necessarily, indicate reluctance; one can obey an order or instruction cheerfully and entusiastically.

Answer (score -2):

We abide ***by*** (comply with, follow) the law, the rules, or a contract, and you can also use obey with those, except for the contract. You obey a teacher, a policeman, a coach, a parent, and so forth.  We do not abide by them.

So, you can use "abide by" with things, and "obey" with things and people.

For more examples of how you can use "abide by," see [here](http://sentencedict.com/abide%20by.html).

Comment: I'm going to upvote you for this, mainly because you have received two quite unjustified down-votes (such petty mindedness, and so discourteous not to explain why). However in this sense "abide" simply means to "remain" or "adhere". Hence to "abide by the law" is really just to "adhere to the law". So "abide" alone is not, in my view synonymous with "obey".

Answer (score -2):

Is it as simple as an active or passive context?  You obey active authority, you abide by passive conditions.

Comment: You don't "obey" conditions.  You abide them, not by them.  Abide there has the meaning of tolerating/enduring something unpleasant.  Abide by means to comply with.

Comment: Please use comments, not "answer" to post opinions.